Cant unlock account and find a Txs in the geth through clef(POA private chain in Centos 7)
about the question（POA private ）
1.Cant not using clef's personal.unlockAccount method to unlock the account in the geth,but can use the personal.listWallets method to list the accounts
2.to use the curl method through the clef to sign Txs,has a correct reponse(including v,r,s,hash and so on),but in the geth cant use the txpool.content method to find the Txs
Code about init chain(c.sh)
#!/bin/bash

#cd Work/Chains/

#number of accounts to create
num_accounts=10

#create accounts with passwords in password.txt
declare -a addresses
for i in $(seq 1 $num_accounts)
do
  output=$(geth account new --datadir /root/Work/Chains/node --password password.txt)
  address=$(echo "$output" | grep -oP 'Public address of the key:\s+\K.*')
  addresses+=($address)
done

#create a genesis.json
alloc=""
for i in $(seq 0 $(($num_accounts-1)))
do
  alloc+="\"${addresses[$i]:2}\": { \"balance\": \"300000\" },"
done

#remove trailing comma
alloc=${alloc%?}

genesis="{
  \"config\": {
    \"chainId\": 20240430,
    \"homesteadBlock\": 0,
    \"eip150Block\": 0,
    \"eip155Block\": 0,
    \"eip158Block\": 0,
    \"byzantiumBlock\": 0,
    \"constantinopleBlock\": 0,
    \"petersburgBlock\": 0,
    \"istanbulBlock\": 0,
    \"berlinBlock\": 0,
    \"clique\": {
      \"period\": 12,
      \"epoch\": 30000
    }
  },
  \"difficulty\": \"1\",
  \"gasLimit\": \"1176000\",
  \"extradata\": \"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000${addresses[0]:2}0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\",
  \"alloc\": {
    $alloc
  }
}"

echo "$genesis" > initBlock.json

#initialize the private blockchain
geth --datadir /root/Work/Chains/node --keystore /root/Work/Chains/node/keystore init initBlock.json

Code about to launch clef in the screen(clef.sh)

#!/bin/bash

# Start a new screen session and run the expect script within that session.
screen -dmS clef_session bash -c 'expect -f /root/Work/Chains/t.exp'
echo "Clef service is starting in a new screen session named 'clef_session'."

Code about start an expect service within a screen session to achieve automatic interaction.(t.exp)

#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# launch clef in the screen
spawn clef --chainid 20240430 --keystore /root/Work/Chains/node/keystore --configdir /root/Work/Chains/node/clef --http --http.addr 0.0.0.0 --http.port 8550

log_file -a /root/Work/Chains/clef_screen.log

while {1} {
    expect {
        "Enter 'ok' to proceed:" {
            send "ok\r"
            exp_continue
        }
        "Approve? \\\[y/N\\\]:" {
            send "y\r"
            exp_continue
        }
        "Please enter the password for account 0x" {
            send "123\r"
            exp_continue
        }
        eof {
            break
        }
        default {
            
            exp_continue
        }
    }
}


interact

Code about launch node(g.sh)

# start geth node
localhost_ip=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')
account_count=$(ls -1q /root/Work/Chains/node/keystore | wc -l)
unlock_string=$(seq -s "," 0 $((account_count-1)))
nohup geth \
--datadir /root/Work/Chains/node \
--keystore /root/Work/Chains/node/keystore \
--networkid 20240430 \
--nat extip:$localhost_ip \
--netrestrict 192.168.0.0/16 \
--http \
--http.port 8545 \
--http.api eth,net,txpool,web3,clique,admin,les \
--port "30303" \
--syncmode "full" \
--unlock $unlock_string \
--password password.txt \
--miner.etherbase=${addresses[0]}
--bootnodes "enr:-KO4QNs5G4YVHuSKcVkYH5jkOkKEk04RyPaQqBIqlvdIJNPUd_1Z81qGkAJHn0x8OmSkYO4IhZ2uP0ly8G_9AmKjkwWGAY9H_s3og2V0aMfGhE0s8niAgmlkgnY0gmlwhMCoAASJc2VjcDI1NmsxoQPZTaDrjWqXcLwSVaDDk1CMCJxvGhs5P7SSr0afi-iUO4RzbmFwwIN0Y3CCdl-DdWRwgnZf" \
--allow-insecure-unlock \
--signer=./node/clef/clef.ipc \
--ws.port 8546 \
2>>./node/geth.log &

Scripts are started in the following order:c.sh，clef.sh，t.exp，g.sh
Only one server was used to start these scripts, and only one node was launched.

Question one
Cant not using clef's personal.unlockAccount method to unlock the account in the geth,but can use the personal.listWallets method to list the accounts
screenshot about clef document

Based on the provided documentation, the operations are performed as follows:

Status part is 'ok,' but it's unclear whether this represents an account being unlocked or not. This is different from what the documentation suggests.
for the unlock account
the screenshot also from clef document

Based on the provided documentation, the operations are performed as follows:

This error occurs when using other parameters or the personal.newAccount() method in the personal.unlockAccount() function of clef
Passphrase input is done using the password.txt file
Question two
to use the curl method through the clef to sign Txs,has a correct reponse(including v,r,s,hash and so on),but in the geth cant use the txpool.content method to find the Txs
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"account_signTransaction","params":[{"from":"0x3802dFFC86F4B6D707F398B763775AF24E1FC07f","gas":"0x333","gasPrice":"0x1","nonce":"0x0","to":"0x89e05D9e2efD4E3AC34F84c6b161fd36CF03164F", "value":"0x12345", "data":"0x4401a6e40000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012"},"safeSend(address)"],"id":67}' http://localhost:8550/



This is a transaction response displayed in the clef interactive interface (handled by the except)
back to the geth,cant no use the txpool.content method to find the transaction

（Maybe I haven't mined? But setting the mining reward account also fails）
